# Is there a way to use a Custom PermissionEvaluator to Authorize endpoints from an imported package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

Java Spring project. We need to add authorization to endpoints imported from another package.

Trying to add authorization using the hasPermission() method from our extension of PermissionEvaluator to API endpoints that we are importing from another package.

Because they're coming from another package, we can't @PreAuthorize them. I see we can make a config file with an advisor with a JdkRegexMethodPointcut for the matching package, but I don't know how to check that the person accessing the method hasPermission() through the PermissionEvaluator.

```
    JdkRegexMethodPointcut pattern = new JdkRegexMethodPointcut();
    pattern.setPattern("package.name");
   AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> rule = //don't know what to put here but something like CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission("APP.READ")
AuthorizationManagerBefofeMethodInterceptor interceptor = new AuthorizationManagerBefofeMethodInterceptor(pattern, rule);
interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.PRE_AUTHORIZE.getOrder() + 1);
```

I suspect this won't work for a few reasons, one of which is adding the interceptor to run after the Pre-authorization means it won't even run for the imported endpoints since they don't have @PreAuthorize annotations

So how do I best approach this please? I've been in circles checking Spring docs for authentication and authorization